# Create Div using button React

Tags: create-react-app

I'm new in React App, i just want to create DIVs after each clicking the button, please help.

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';


function App() {
  function handleSubmit() {
    let div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerText = document.getElementById('getText').innerText;
    document.body.appendChild(div);
    }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
       <button>Click me!</button>
       <div id="getText"> INNER TEXT</div>
       </form>
      </header>
    </div>
  )}


export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep a state on the number of times you click the button (`count`). Then you can use a for loop to create how many number of `div` you need to add.

```
import { useState } from "react";

const divCreator = (total) => {
  const divArray = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < total; i++) {
    divArray.push(
      <div id="getText" key={i}>
        INNER TEXT
      </div>
    );
  }
  return divArray;
};

function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  function handleSubmit() {
    setCount((state) => state + 1);
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <button onClick={handleSubmit}>Click me!</button>
        {divCreator(count)}
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Application View**

[image]

Comment: Thank you mate ! does it work that each div will have different color ?

Comment: It's also possible to set different font colour to div content. So you have to manage that inside the loop. You can manage it similar to the way I'm setting `key` prop inside the `div`, if you want to set a different colour to each `div`.

Comment: yess it worked. I used random rgb inside the function divCreator. But can you help me on something. I am trying to delete any of the div by clicking on it. Can you help me with it ?